# What is the meaning of “knobbie”

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the word “knobbie”
from Words and phrases http://www.wordandphrase.info/
[image]

Comment: The Google search [ define "knobbie" ] returns links to the answer including the very first hit: Bing Dictionary. This is off topic: General Reference.

Answer (score 3):

All of the reference are to bicycles.

> - ...miniature mountain bikes, they're complete with hand brakes, knobbies and aluminum rims.
> - And when you're talking rolling resistance, they've got knobbies beat by a country mile.
> - ...the course: racing slicks for roads, off-road knobbies for rugged hills.

The last gives it away: the word refers to knobbled tyres, as opposed to "slick" (smooth) tyres. It's jargon, but easy to see that it's related to the listed adjective *knobby*:

> Full of, abounding in, bearing, or covered with knobs or protuberances; knotty. [OED]

Here's a motorcycle/motocross version from a Google image search for *knobbies*. Bikes would have smaller knobs on.

[image]
[[Adventure Rider]](http://www.advrider.com/forums/showthread.php?t=224100)

There's a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knobby_tire) too.

Answer (score 1):

This is an informal variant of [*knobby tire.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knobby_tire)